# Using jQuery when to defer ajax processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a list of 15+ ajax requests that need to be called in a specific order.  I need each ajax call to wait until the previous function finishes before making the next call.  This issue arises because my ajax call, has a direct callback that is also an ajax call.

```
createCheckIn() {
    this.selectedList = [...] // long list of objects
    count = 0

    for ( i=0; i < this.selectedList.length; i++ ) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: {
                check_in: {
                    client_id: this.selectClient.id,
                    program_id: this.program_id
                }
            },
            success: function(res) {
                that.createWeighIn(count, res.id)
                count = count + 1
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
    }
},
createWeighIn(index, check_in_id) {
    let data = {}
    let that = this
    data.weigh_in = this.selectedList[index]

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function(res) {
            console.log(res)
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
}
```

the correct data is generated but I believe the ordering is off because eventually there is a call to `createCheckIn()` that begins before the previous entry has completed.

**Is there a way to chain these functions such that `createCheckIn()` and `createWeighIn()` are called (and complete) before `selectedList` iterates.**

Comment: you want createCheckIn to be complete before selectedList iterates, but selectedList iterates inside createCheckIn, dont get it

Comment: @AniketSahrawat `async: false` is deprecated. See here https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-open()-method

Comment: I think the problem is that you're creating a bunch of ajax requests basically all at once in the for loop, and expecting them to finish processing in the same order they were created.

Comment: may be look into `Promises`. MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 0):

your `for` loop in `createCheckIn()` will not stop to wait on your ajax return.  you can do something like:

```
function createCheckIn(oldI, oldCount){
    var count = 0;
    var currentI = 0;
    if(oldCount != null){
      count = oldCount;
    }
    if(oldI != null){
      currentI = oldI;
    }
    if(currentI < this.selectedList.length){
      $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: url,
          data: {
              check_in: {
                  client_id: this.selectClient.id,
                  program_id: this.program_id
              }
          },
          success: function(res) {
              that.createWeighIn(count, res.id)
              createCheckIn(currentI + 1, count + 1);
          },
          error: function(err) {
              console.log(err)
          }

      }); //ajax
    }  // if
}
```

seems likely that you can eliminate one of those counters too, the `i` or the `count`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is missing some potentially really important details about what you need to do leading up to this (ie. `this.selectedItems` generation) and what happens after (what if one call checkin fails, what if a checkin succeeds but its corresponding weighIn fails, etc..). That said...

It seems you are not actually using the counter for anything other than to reference data you already have, so why not just pass that in directly like:

```
createWeighIn(weighInData, check_in_id) {
    let data = {};
    let that = this;
    data.weigh_in = weighInData;
    // ... your other code
}
```

I would make `createCheckIn` only handle doing the ajax request and making a **single** "reservation" in your system. Then i would make a new method called `checkIn` that uses the two previous method to process all of selected items:

```
checkIn() {
    let self = this;
    let promises = [];
    let this.selectedList = [...];

    for (let = 0; i < this.selectedList.length; i++) {
        // always create the deferred outside the call
        let def = $.Deferred();
        promises.push(def.promise());

        this.createCheckIn().done(function (res) {
            self.createWeighIn(self.selectedList[i], res.id))
                .done(function () {
                    // resolve
                    def.resolve.apply(def, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
                })
                .fail(function () {
                    def.reject.apply(def, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
                });
        }).fail(function () {
           // if checkin fails, always reject because we know weighIn wont be called
           def.reject.apply(def, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        });
    };

    // this will resolve/fail when all promises (from createWeighIn) resolve/fail
    return $.when.apply(null, promises);
}
```

so putting it all together:

```
{
    createCheckIn() {
        let request = $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: {
                    check_in: {
                        client_id: this.selectClient.id,
                        program_id: this.program_id
                    }
                }
            })
            .fail(function(err) {
                console.log(err)
            });
        };

        return request;
    },
    createWeighIn(data, check_in_id) {
        let params = {};

        params.weigh_in = data;

        let request = $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: params,
            success: function(res) {
                console.log(res)
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        });

        return request;
    },

    checkIn() {
        let self = this;
        let promises = [];
        let this.selectedList = [...];

        for (let = 0; i < this.selectedList.length; i++) {
            // always create the deferred outside the call
            let def = $.Deferred();
            promises.push(def.promise());

            this.createCheckIn().done(function (res) {
                self.createWeighIn(self.selectedList[i], res.id))
                    .done(function () {
                        // resolve
                        def.resolve.apply(def, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
                    })
                    .fail(function () {
                        def.reject.apply(def, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
                    });
            }).fail(function () {
               // if checkin fails, always reject because we know weighIn wont be called
               def.reject.apply(def, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            });
        };

        // this will resolve/fail when all promises (from createWeighIn) resolve/fail
        return $.when.apply(null, promises);
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up using promises and some recursion to solve it.  But the topic is very new to me so I may have made some errors.  I submitted it as an answer in case it helps people down the line

Answer (score 0):

I ended up introducing promises, and some recursion and removing the loop altogether.  I basically begin the process by calling `createCheckIn()` with an index of 0:

```
this.createCheckIn(0)

createCheckIn(index) {
    this.selectedList = [...] // long list of objects
    count = 0

    let prom = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: {
                check_in: {
                    client_id: that.selectClient.id,
                    program_id: that.program_id
                }
            },
            success: function(res) {
                resolve(that.createWeighIn(index, res.id))
            },
            error: function(err) {
                reject(console.log(err))
            }
        })
    })
},
createWeighIn(index, check_in_id) {
    let data = {}
    let that = this
    data.weigh_in = this.selectedList[index]

    let prom = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success: function(res) {
                console.log(res)
                if ( index == (that.selectedList.length - 1) ) {
                    that.complete = true
                    resolve(console.log("complete"))
                } else {
                    index++
                    resolve(that.createCheckIn(index))
                }
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
    })
}
```